# Orange Juice, Milk, or Beer

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Suppose that  we have $n$ dollars and that each day we buy either orange juice for a dollar, milk for two dollars, or beer for two dollars. If $R_n$ is the number of ways of spending all the money, show that
$$R_n=R_{n-1}+2R_{n-2}.$$

---

How can I see this in another way? I mean like in a steps-along-a-grid kind of way, or maybe that's useless...

---

Order is taken into account, as, for example there are $11$ ways to spend $ \$4$:
$$MB, BM, OOM, OOB, OMO, OBO, MOO, BOO, OOOO, MM, BB$$

Comment: There's just one way of spending your $n$ dollars. Buy $n/2$ beers and one OJ for the morning after (if you have a dollar left)!

Comment: Wow, can't ask for a more practical question for a college student.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If order is taken into account, then notice that to use $n$ dollars, you will make your final purchase with either $1$ dollar remaining, or $2$ dollars remaining.  In the first case, you can only purchase orange juice, and in the second, you have two options, milk or beer.

See if you can translate the previous sentences into a recurrence relation.

Comment: You said it exactly. Hmm... I wonder sometimes what it is to "show" or to "demonstrate" or to "prove." Seems arbitrary most of the time. Like what you said was obvious, but I mean is that it? That's all that needs to be said?

Comment: I always assume the problem requires rigor...

Comment: Whatever that means..[.](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-PyZGCzc5u3g/UfXwfC8QACI/AAAAAAAAKv0/ZjUEjVjN-us/s346/handerpants-large.jpg)